# While running my java code for LDAP, the code does not throw an error, but I see connection is not in established status but in TIME_WAIT

Tags: java, ldap

While running my java code for LDAP, the code does not throw an error, but I see connection is not in established status but in TIME_WAIT. In the backend I see connection is not established. The code does not throw any error.

```
public static void validateLoginLDAP(String userName) throws AuthenticationException {

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://MY URL:389/o=TheNational");
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"uid=TestUser,ou=Re,ou=Admin,ou=b,o=TheNational");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"Password1");

        DirContext  ctx;
        try {

            ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            System.out.println(ctx.getEnvironment());

        } catch (NamingException e) {
          System.out.println(e);
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the backend i see connection is not established.The code does not throw any error

Answer (score 0):

The *port* is in TIME_WAIT state. The connection no longer exists. The TIME_WAIT state lasts for a couple of minutes for TCP integrity reasons.

There is no problem here.

Comment: how do i make sure that my connection is done properly then

Comment: I've already answered that. At this point there is no connection. It is done. There is no problem here.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to make the connection then.

Comment: You've already made the connection. Otherwise the port could never have got into TIME_WAIT state. None of this is making any sense whatsoever.

Comment: Please dont get me wrong,i am new to this.The issue is when i am manually connecting ldap,i can see in the backend connection is established.But when i am running my code it is always in TIME_WAIT